# NoSuchFieldError in Android Integration test with maven

Tags: android, maven, android-testing

I have an Android Maven Project and I want to implement an instrument test, which should be run by maven of course.

However I get NoSuchMethodError and NoSuchFieldError.

I have three modules in my maven project.

1. The core library, in which I have defined the DBHelper class
2. The android application project.
3. The android instrumentation test project.

When I execute `mvn clean install` maven successfully executes everything until the android instrumentation-test is executed on an real android device.

When I do start the app myself and click on the buttons where the instrumentation test fails I do not get any errors. So I think there must be something wrong with the pom.xml of my android instrumentation test.

So here is how I defined the dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.dornathal</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.dornathal</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <type>apk</type>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.dornathal</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

I do not define any scopes so all classes should be available in the runtime and test scope, I think.

The DBHelper class contains `public static final String[]`'s like

```
public static final String[] SET_ACTION_LIST = {KEY_ID, KEY_PARENT_ID, KEY_ACTION_ID, KEY_SORT_ORDER, KEY_TYPE_ENUM};
```

This field is called by a class of the application project (in the onCreateMethod):

```
result += printDatabase(db, DBHelper.TABLE_ACTION_LIST, DBHelper.SET_ACTION_LIST);
```

The strange thing to notice is, that this line is not the first one that accesses a field of DBHelper. There are a dozen similar lines accessing a field of DBHelper (but of course with different fieldnames).

As the application runs fine everything above cannot be uncorrect.

And finally I have the instrumentation test with robotium:

```
    @Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    this.setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
}


public void testOpenActivitiesOfMain(){
    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.ShowDatabase));
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Does not start the Database",Database.class);
    solo.goBack();
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Does not return from Database", MainPage.class);}
```

Now there are the following Error outputs: 
Maven:

```
[INFO] 01498A031900801A_samsung_GalaxyNexus :   Running instrumentation tests in de.dornathal.planyourmeals.android.test
[INFO] 01498A031900801A_samsung_GalaxyNexus :     Run started: de.dornathal.planyourmeals.android.test, 4 tests:
[INFO] 01498A031900801A_samsung_GalaxyNexus :       Start [1/4]: de.dornathal.planyourmeals.android.test.MainPageTest#testOpenActivitiesOfMain
[INFO] 01498A031900801A_samsung_GalaxyNexus :       ERROR:de.dornathal.planyourmeals.android.test.MainPageTest#testOpenActivitiesOfMain
[INFO] 01498A031900801A_samsung_GalaxyNexus :       Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError''. Check device logcat for details
[INFO] 01498A031900801A_samsung_GalaxyNexus :       End [1/4]: de.dornathal.planyourmeals.android.test.MainPageTest#testOpenActivitiesOfMain
[INFO] 01498A031900801A_samsung_GalaxyNexus :     Run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError'
[INFO] 01498A031900801A_samsung_GalaxyNexus :     Run ended: 0 ms
[ERROR] 01498A031900801A_samsung_GalaxyNexus :     FAILURES!!!
```

and the logcat says

```
11-16 12:07:36.529: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4581): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: de.dornathal.planyourmeals.core.database.DBHelper.SET_ACTION_LIST
    at de.dornathal.planyourmeals.android.view.DatabasePager$DatabaseFragment.onCreateView(DatabasePager.java:42)
```

If anyone has a suggestion on how this could work or where the actual error could occure I am very thankfully on any advice.

MFG Dornathal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NoSuchMethodError or NoSuchFieldError is often thrown when the class was updated but not complete recompiled.

It turned out that I did change the SNAPSHOT version of my library project so that maven loaded an old version.

If you want to test if that could be the same issue with your project, try to remove the folder with the SNAPSHOT versions from your local maven repository. (`C:\Users\<username>\.m2\...\yourLibrary\`)

If you rerun maven after that and you get an error saying that maven did'nt find that SNAPSHOT.jar, check if all version numbers match in your poms.